# Image is not shown after image is selected from react-native image-picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am developing an application in which i need to upload an image from phone camera and also from gallery . camera & gallery is not showing image inside image tag.

here is my code

```
function profile({ route,navigation }) {
    const [imageUri, setimageUri] = useState('');



    const openCamera = () => {
        let options={
            storageOptions: {
                path: 'images',
                mediaType: 'photo',
            },
        };
        launchCamera(options, response => {
            console.log("response =", response);
            if(response.didCancel){
                console.log('user cancelled image picker');
            }else if(response.error){
                console.log('Image picker Error:', response.error);
            }else if(response.customButton){
                console.log('User taped cutom button:', response.customButton);
            }else{
                const source = {uri: 'data: image/jpeg;base64,'+ response.base64 };
                setimageUri(source);    
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is image view code

```
<Image
  source={imageUri}
  style={{
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 100,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,It will help you

```
function profile({ route,navigation }) {
    const [imageUri, setimageUri] = useState('');

    const openCamera = () => {
        let options={
            storageOptions: {
                path: 'images',
                mediaType: 'photo',
            },
        };
        launchCamera(options, response => {
            console.log("response =", response);
            if(response.didCancel){
                console.log('user cancelled image picker');
            }else if(response.error){
                console.log('Image picker Error:', response.error);
            }else if(response.customButton){
                console.log('User taped cutom button:', response.customButton);
            }else{
                setimageUri(response.assets[0].uri);    
            }
        });
    }


<Image
  source={{ uri: imageUri }}
  style={{
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 100,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  }}
/>
```

`response` will give you `assets` array you can access image `uri` as `response.assets[0].uri`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but still not working getting "Failed prop type: invalid prop `source` Supplied to `image`. " this warning.

Comment: <Image source={require(imageUri)} style={{height: 100, width: 100, borderRadius: 100, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black', alignSelf: 'center',}} /> i think this format is right to add require but getting error "invalid call at line"

Comment: check my edited answer. it will work now. Use `uri`  inside Image source.

Comment: Thanks buddy this time it works , your answer help me alot.